# Magento 1.9.4.2 infected by ransomware?

Tags: magento-1.9

I scanned my website on [magentary.com](https://magentary.com/magento-security-patch-tester/) and I read that it is ransomware infected and there is an adminer unprotected.
How I can find the infection? Where I find adminer on the server?

I launched a clamav scan on the server and I didn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: is it version 1.4 (as in your title) or version 1.9 (as you tagged)? I changed the tag to 1.4 (as per your title) but it looks like you changed it back to 1.9

Comment: Actually it is 1.9.4.2. Thanks.

Comment: I think its a false positve, a put a few magento site I know in it as they all are getting that "ransomware: infected"... but not the Adminer warning

Comment: But I didn't find adminer in any way. Actually on my site I'm having some problems with paypal module, I guess an injection that can make changes to paypal module.

Answer (score 0):

you can run fast search for any files:

index all your files:

```
yum install mlocate
updatedb
locate adminer.php
```

using `find` command from magento root:

```
find . -name adminer*
```

scan `skin` folder for suspicious `.php` files:

```
find skin/ -name "*\.php"
```

install `mwscan` , it detects many magento malware code:

```
yum -y install python-pip python-devel gcc
pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade mwscan
mwscan .
```

check `js/varien/` folder, malware usually injected into javascript files.

configure `auditctl` to log:

```
auditctl -w /home/magento/ -p wa -k mage_malware
```

then check whats going on:

```
ausearch -k mage_malware | aureport -f -i


File Report
===============================================
# date time file syscall success exe auid event
===============================================
1. 05/24/2019 16:09:34 /home/magento/app/Mage.php open yes /usr/sbin/nginx unset 324771
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-)

I didn't find adminer.php, maybe it is a false warning?

I installed mwscan and "<no events of interest were found>".

In /js/varien/ I don't see anything strange, I scanned them with desktop antivirus and i didn't receive any warning.

About auditctl is it possible configure it for any site on the server?

Comment: I launched a new sca with clamav on the whole server and i got some messages. I'm not sure I can trust it. I uploaded it on https://we.tl/t-8cDdjWw3Pl